# UISearchController searchbar overlaps CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, overlap, uisearchcontroller

When launching UISearchController programatically the UISearchBar overlaps CollectionView below.

I've searched here and there and seems that no one had this kind of problem before.

[image]
[image]

There are some limitations on how i can and cannot do it:

- cannot use tableview header
- cannot use collectionview header
- have to use collectionviewcontroller

Already tried Adjust Scroll View Insets and Extend Edges - no use because its a CollectionViewController

The question is: how to do it the right way, using IBAction?
The code for IBAction connected to the magnifying glass is:

```
@IBAction func showSearchBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: As I recall UISearchController has a delegate method, something like becomeActive. Have you tried to change the insets of the collectionView in that method?

Comment: That doesn't look at all correct... How do you have two status bars? Can you create a small project that reproduces this result?

Comment: These are not Status Bars, it's Top Bar. When UISearchController gets called, as in code above, it replaces standard Top Bar with UISearchBar interface. Once UISearchBar is dismissed with **Cancel** button, the standard Top Bar is back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @noir_eagle suggestion I've implemented completion block for `present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)` method, so it looks like this:

```
present(searchController, animated: true, completion: {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            self.collectionView?.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -64)
        })
    })
```

I had to do it in this method because `UISearchControllerDelegate` method `didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController)` and `willPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController)` are never called... Dunno why.

Next, somehow, method `didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController)` of `UISearchControllerDelegate` is called right after dismissing `UISearchBar` with **Cancel** button, so I've implemented this:

```
func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    })
}
```

And it was good... smooth animation, until I've realized that the property `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` is **true**, so all I have to do is set it to **false**.

That's it, no need for `contentInset` or `contentOffset` animation!
The final solution looks like this:

```
@IBAction func showSearchBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```